# Proxmox и проброс портов

Tags: linux, iptables, proxmox

Столкнулся с такой проблемой в proxmox.
Есть две виртуальные машины с windows, на них крутятся приложения на iis.
Во внешнюю сеть проброс портов осуществляется через iptables:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d внешний_айпи -p tcp --dport 3810  -j DNAT --to-destination 10.101.0.134:3810.
Приложения видны в интернете, но если пробую по домену и порту обратится к приложению с сервера1 через север 2, то оно не открывается.
Пробовал добавить правило forward, но и это не принесло результатов.
В чем может быть проблема?

UPD: Настройка интерфейсов на proxmox:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
    dns-nameservers XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
    up route add -net XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  netmask 255.255.255.192 gw XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  dev eth0

iface eth1 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/24
    gateway XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
    bridge-ports eth0
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
    bridge-vlan-aware yes
    bridge-vids 2-4094

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
    address 10.101.0.1/24
    bridge-ports none
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
    bridge-vlan-aware yes
    bridge-vids 2-4094
    
    post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    post-up /etc/network/firewall.sh
    post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.101.0.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
    post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.101.0.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Сети разные? Пинги идут?

Comment: подсеть одна  10.101.0.0/24 по ней пинг идет

Comment: Обращаешься по fqdn или по ip? Если по ip - по внутреннему или по внешнему?

Comment: по fqdn и по внешнему ip не проходит подключение( а мне надо именно так) , а по внутреннему работает все ок

Comment: Ну а чё пишет, когда не проходит? А курл чё говорит? А логи на стороне тачек чё говорят? А если по fqdn из соседней вируалки ломиться?